# Does the Mono C# compiler do any parallelization of a loop at compile time?

Tags: c#, mono, compiler-optimization

not much more than the title says. If I do:

```
  int[] arr = new int[(long)Math.Pow(2, 25)];
  for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
    arr[j] = j;
```

will the compiler parallelize this code in any way? I'm asking because I see 3 of the 4 cores light up when run.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the sum of the utilization go over 100%?  Unless the threads have some affinity to a particular core, there's nothing keeping a single thread from hopping from core to core.

Comment: good point, @recursive. It does go over 100%, but that may just be other tasks that get some running time in between, like `top` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, by default I believe that no it doesn't; because MS.Net doesn't.

That's not to say that .Net isn't firing on all your cores, but the snippet you posted should be a single thread operation.